# Use Open ID connect with auth code flow Azure AD

Tags: javascript, express, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, passport-azure-ad

I am working on authentication of a NodeJS, Express Web application where I want users to be routed to microsoft SSO. I am using passport azure ad and open id connect to do this.

However what I want to know is -

Is it only possible to do Open ID connect with implicit grant? Or c
Can we do open id connect with auth flow? If so, does passport-azure-ad support it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request) of OpenID Connect, it will request a id_token when send the sign-in request(the `response_type` is "id_token"). And we can see from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) of auth code flow, the `response_type` is "code". But we according to this [tutorial](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#Combinations), the `response_type` could also be "**code id_token**" in auth code flow.

[image]

So we can also do open id connect in auth code flow.

If you want to use passport-azure-ad, here is a [method](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-passport-azure-ad/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.passport-azure-ad.OIDCStrategy.prototype._authCodeFlowHandler)(for auth code flow) for your reference.
[image]
The `params` are items we get from the request or metadata, such as id_token, code, policy, metadata, cacheKey, etc

The `oauthConfig` are items needed for oauth flow (like redirection, code redemption), such as token_endpoint, userinfo_endpoint, etc

The `optionsToValidate` are items we need to validate id_token against, such as issuer, audience, etc

Hope it helps~